# Performance issues with Infragistics WebExcelExporter.Export(webdatagrid, worksheet) with large data sets

Tags: c#, export-to-excel, infragistics, webdatagrid

I am using  `Infragistics WebExcelExporter.Export(webdatagrid, worksheet)` to export large datatable having 70000+ rows and 25 columns. The export fails due to timeouts. Is there any other way to export with Infragistics WebExcelExporter.

Works without any issues if the rows are below 50000.

Answer (score 0):

This is definetely a big amout of data. Server is stuck in a loop or the server is still processing the request. My suggestion is to increase the time which is needed to process your data (from the long running methods) and to see if the error is caused by insufficient time or infinitive loop.

The default callback manager timeout value is 20 seconds. You could use the protected _callbackManager object which is referenced by each Aikido control. To increase the WebDataGrid timeout period you can do the following:

Code snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function Init(sender, eventArgs) {
            sender._callbackManager.setTimeout(60000);
        }
 </script>


 ...
<ig:WebDataGrid ID="WebDataGrid1" runat="server" DataSourceID="EmployeesDataSource" 
    Width="100%" DataKeyFields="OrderID">
    <ClientEvents Initialize="Init" />
```

Have you considered exporting this amout of data on different portions?

Comment: thank you for the answer.  Server was returning response ontime. The failure is with Infragistics library. If fails with large data sets. Later came to know that this is a know issue with infragistics library.  I replaced infragistics with OpenXML and the processing is very quick.